# How do I bundle two tensors together in Tensorflow Batches?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to create a loss that's simultaneously on a reconstruction of X and a function of the labels y in tensorflow.  The two need to match, and I'm using `tf.data.Dataset.batch()` and gradient tape instead of directly calling `.fit(, batch = number)` such as you might usually use. To solve the problem I thought of a couple of approaches:

1. Bundle together X and Y as a tuple and turn that tuple into a tensorflow dataset and try to unpack after using `.batch()`
2. Just tack the y on to the end of the X tensor and separate the two later after using `.batch()`

Is there any standard way to achieve this kind of thing? I'm not sure if the two above approaches are hacky, but it seems like number 2 might work at least but I'm also wondering if I've greatly overcomplicated the process. My data loading setup for the x's only at the moment looks something like this:

```
train_dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_dataset)
                 .shuffle(len(training_ind))
                 .batch(bsize))
```

And what I'm envisioning is something like:

```
train_x_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_x)
train_y_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_y)

train_datset = (tf.data.Dataset((train_x_dataset,train_y_dataset))
                     .shuffle(len(training_ind))
                     .batch(bsize))

for train_x, train_y in train_dataset:
  loss(train_step(model, train_x, train_y, optimizer))
```

Comment: You can use [`tf.data.Dataset.zip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip) to iterate through two datasets at the same time. Is that what you need?

Comment: @jakub this does look like more or less what I'm trying to do (fingers crossed it's compatible with batch).  I'll play with it a bit and see if it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was solved much easier than I expected. Essentially I already had the basic idea of passing the two datasets as tuples, the only difference is that you have to pass both WHEN you call `.from_tensor_slices`, not after. Then accessing the elements are pretty much as expected.

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x,train_y))

train_dataset = (train_dataset
                     .shuffle(n_obs)
                     .batch(bsize))

for train_x, train_y in train_dataset:
  loss(train_step(model, train_x, train_y, optimizer))
```